# css hover and immidiatily precedent not working

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, tooltip

I want to make a reusable tooltip. The span following the image is not showed, when you go over it the span must appear. But is doesn't work. Does anybody has an idea? The span stay forever in display none.

Html code

```
<div>
    <div>Sharing</div>
    <img class="info-tooltip" src="system-help.png" alt="Info">
    <span>sdfmhdsjlfhsdljkqhfjkldsqfhljkqdshflsqd</span>
</div>
```

ccs code

```
.info-tooltip + span{
    display: none;
}
.info-tooltip:hover + span{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 105px;
    line-height:8px;
    top:10px;
    left:15px;
    background-color: #E9F2FF;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#444444;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    z-index:100040000;
}
```

Comment: It is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aq8gA/ What is your problem exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to surround your image with a div tag:

```
<div class="info-tooltip"><img src="system-help.png" alt="Info"></div>
```